# Prallax Effect with text

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, parallax

On my website, I want to use a kind of parallax effect. But normally you only fix a background picture to the screen and so allow the scrolling 'over' it, what I want is kind of the same thing with all of my content.

The website is a one-page side with several sections. Ea h of the sections has a min-height of 100vh on landscape screens. If say section 1, is in the viewport, the user should scroll normally, until the very bottom of the section reaches the bottom of the screen. At the moment of which the next container enters the viewport, section 1 should be fixed, so that section 2 slides over section 1 like a sheet of paper and covers first the content of the bottom.

Have you any idea on how to do this? I don't need fully coded examples, just some ideas on how you would do this.

Thanks in advance.

---

**Some more details**

I think that my explanation of what I'm trying to get is a bit vague, so I'm going to extend this a bit.

Imagine you have 5 sheets of paper, on every sheet, there is some content, let's say an *About* section, on another sheet some *Features* and so on. Now every sheet has a height of your viewport, so all that you see is that sheet of paper. If the content is bigger than your viewport, the sheet gets bigger too. This is quite obvious I think. If you scroll down the page, the sheet of paper, you're seeing should scroll up until its end matches with the viewport border. Now instead of moving up when scrolling this sheet of paper stays at that exact place. The new content on sheet 2 slides over it, like a new layer.

Comment: You mean something like this for every slide? https://jsfiddle.net/3r1Lm4ha/1/ if thats it, you just have to keep track of the scroll position and change the fixed class to the current element

Comment: @ToniMichelCaubet You're awesome. That's exactly what I meant. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you mean something like this?

```
<main>
  <section class="orange fixed">
    <h2>
      Some text
    </h2>
  </section>
  <section class="blue">
    <h2>
      Some text
    </h2>
  </section>
  <section class="orange">
    <h2>
      Some text
    </h2>
  </section>
</main>
```

JS:

```
var $sections = $('main section');
var sectionHeight = $sections.eq(0).outerHeight();
var setCurrent = function(position ) {
    $sections.eq(position).addClass('fixed').siblings().removeClass('fixed');  
}

$(window).on('scroll', function() {
  var scTop = $(window).scrollTop();
  var position = Math.ceil( scTop / sectionHeight );
  setCurrent( position - 1 );

})
```

And some sass

```
body {
  margin: 0;
}

main {
  padding: 0;
  padding-top: 100vh; // this is the trick
  section {
    height: 100vh;
    text-align: center;
    color: white;
    padding-top: 200px;
    position: relative;
    margin: 0;
    h2 {
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
    }
    &.orange {
      background: orange;
    }
    &.blue {
      background: blue;
    }
    &.fixed { // this is the trick
      position: fixed;
      left: 0;
      top: 0;
      width: 100%;
    }
  }
}
```

You can test it here

https://jsfiddle.net/3r1Lm4ha/8/ ( Maybe more updated )

PS: Could be improved but still don't know if this is what you are looking for